# How do we create and Manage Azure Keyvault Secrets using Azure Service Operators?

Tags: azure, operators, azure-keyvault, azure-secrets

I am trying to create and manage Azure Keyvault Secrets using the Azure Service Operators.

I can see the options to create and manage the Keyvault certificate using the kind: KeyVaultKey. However, I am wondering how I can create and manage secrets using the Azure Service Operators.

Is there any lead on this?

Appreciate the help..!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Key Vault operator suite consists of the following operators:

•   KeyVault - Deploys an Azure Key Vault given the location and resource group

•   KeyVaultKey - Deploys an Azure Key Vault key given the location and resource group

The KeyVaultKey operator serves as an operator that allows for declarative management of Key Vault keys - one of the three resources available for storage and management in Key Vault; keys, secrets, and certificates. Keys can be leveraged for various use cases.

You can find sample code [Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-operator/blob/master/config/samples/azure_v1alpha1_keyvaultkey.yaml)

Reference for [Azure service operator](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-operator)

Note: Azure service operator is still under development